# Custom validation control of image not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have this code:

```
protected void registerBtn_click(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool agencyPictureActive = agencypicture.HasFile;
            agencypictureValidator.Enabled = agencyPictureActive;

            Page.Validate();

            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
```

and this control:

```
<asp:label runat="server">Logo</asp:label> 
<asp:FileUpload id="agencypicture" runat="server"/> 
<asp:CustomValidator id="agencypictureValidator" 

ValidationGroup="userForm" 
ControlToValidate="agencypicture" 
ErrorMessage="some error msg" Text="*" 
OnServerValidate="checkImageSizeValidate" 
runat="server">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

I want to validate and save the image along with other form value upon "registerBtn_click" , but the custom validation control of the image does not activate somehow... why?

This is my submit control:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnSubmit" OnClick="registerBtn_click"  
ValidationGroup="userForm" Text="Submit" runat="server">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem: when I click on the linkbutton, it tries to go through client validation, and since client validation doesn't succeed, registerBtn_click for server validation does not get called? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
PostBackUrl="~/MyPage.aspx"
```

in my submit link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag?